# Voltage and current at Points Throughout a Circuit

Tags: electric-current, voltage

In a series circuit an electric field is created between both terminals of the battery . Is the movement of charges in a wire affected by the position of those charges within that wire? , eg would the charges at nearer the cathode have greater electric potential energy (and hence a greater acceleration) than those nearer to the anode ?

Comment: Voltage is always in reference to paths between two points (in electronics all paths usually have the same voltage so then its easier to talk about voltage between points). So I don't think electronics alone is enough to answer. (Sorry sloppy reading :( )

Answer (score 0):

Once steady state is reached, the movement of electrons is dictated by field produced by local surface charges on the wire, not by the charges at the terminal of the battery.  The electric field, and hence the acceleration of the charge carriers, is constant throughout the wire.